# What's the purpose of Service's stopSelfResult method? The real use case would be perfect.

Tags: android, service

I see that if I'll keep track of startIds passed to onStartCommant then I can use the last one to stop the service. If I invoke stopSelfResult with starttId that is not the last one then service won't terminate.

So the question is how stopSelfResult can be used in real life?

Answer (score 1):

See AOSP packages/apps/Mms/src/com/android/mms/transaction/SmsReceiver.java

```
 86     /**
 87      * Called back by the service when it has finished processing notifications,
 88      * releasing the wake lock if the service is now stopping.
 89      */
 90     public static void finishStartingService(Service service, int startId) {
 91         synchronized (mStartingServiceSync) {
 92             if (mStartingService != null) {
 93                 if (service.stopSelfResult(startId)) {
 94                     mStartingService.release();
 95                 }
 96             }
 97         }
 98     }
```